# How to create an error message in Visual Basic 6.0 when adding duplicate data to SQL Database?

Tags: vb6

I have a problem about my visual basic 6 program, I want to add an error message when a duplicate value is added by the user (I'm using SQL database). I tried a lot of codes but none of these works, I just deleted some of it. Here's the code. What code should I put to make it run? Please help, thanks in advance.

[It is just a sample one, and I'm going to put the code to my original program if i am going to make it run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvgxL.jpg)

Comment: Hello, instead of using image, you can use the icon {} to insert code in your post. Also you should first show us what did you try, in your code there is nothing saying that you tryed to detect a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what do you consider as a duplicate line. A line with a IDNO that already exists or a line with IDNO and NAME that already exists?

Regardless the answer, you need to:

1. Define a unique key containing the fields that cannot have duplicate values. You must find out how to do that in your database management system. By doing that, you will have the guarantee that you will never have a duplicate line in your database.
2. Add a previous query to your code where you verify if there is a line in your table that already has the values you are trying to insert.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my specified line for identifying the exist record is IDNO, so how do i code that in vb 6 ? i want to make my own error message not the default message "VIOLATION OF PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT"...

Comment: One way would be an error handler. Other way: Before insert, check the value with a select, if the value exists. But you need the error handler too, because in the few microseconds between your check and your insert another one could insert the value (it´s a database)

Comment: Using the constraint is my preferred method because it insures the data integrity and I would do this even if I am checking for the records existence before inserting a new record. Use the error handler to examine  the err and show a more user friendly message.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.

You could trap the error and check the error code/message, if it is "VIOLATION OF PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT" display the error message of your choice.

Personally I would check to see if it exists before the insert and if it does display the "The data you are trying to add already exists" message (or whatever it is you want to display).

On a side note you should look at Parameterized Queries.  The query you have is open to SQL Injection. Take a look at [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548787-Database-Why-should-I-use-Parameters-instead-of-putting-values-into-my-SQL-string)